# How to calculate the derivative of the angular momentum vector $ d\vec L = d(\hat I \vec \omega)?$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, differentiation, calculus, rigid-body-dynamics

My last question, but also the most important one How to calculate the derivative of the angular momentum vector?
$$ d\vec L = d(\hat I \vec \omega)$$
I'm especially interested in derivative tensor to vector for the law of conservation of angular momentum for a rotating rigid body.
$$ d(\hat I \vec \omega)=0$$

I would like to note that the change of the moment of inertia $d \hat I$ must result in change vector $\vec L$ and there must be a second element $d \vec \omega$ that compensates for this change that the angular momentum vector remains unchanged.

I have a solution that is strange but has not been verified by me yet and for now I will not give my answer. So maybe someone will show me how to calculate this derivative.

Unfortunately I have no way of answering this question here (I'm banned again because my results aren't what physicists want) and from what you can see no one here knows the answer (the question is on a different difficulty level), therefore links my answer with my calculations

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3961640/

and link to proof of derivative correctness

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4044211/

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_%28rigid_body_dynamics%29

Comment: @G.Smith When rotating a rigid body with different major moments of inertia there is a change in the moment of inertia dI. Can you explain me how to calculate this change in moment of inertia and how this change affects the angular velocity vector?

Comment: The usual method is to work in the rotating frame where the moments of inertia are *not* changing, as in the Wikipedia article. Once you have solved for the motion in this frame, I think you can transform back to the lab frame. Goldstein’s *Classical Mechanics* has a good chapter on rigid body motion. I haven’t looked at it in decades but it might deal with both frames.

Comment: @G.Smith "The usual method is to work ... where the moments of inertia are not changing..." I'm glad you noticed it too and here is the problem. I couldn't find it anywhere but most likely I was able to calculate it. It works fine for a few cases I've checked, but I don't know if it will always work properly and I don't know how to check it. And unfortunately, my solution will be controversial once again, therefore I will refrain from describing here for now.